# AngularJS: How can i make a page inactive for some time using a timer countdown stored in the cookie?

Tags: angularjs

I am storing a timestamp in the cookie, and after 3 failed login attempts by a user, i need to prevent the user from accessing the login page for sometime,say in this case 10seconds. I prevent the access to login page by poping up a counter modal for 10 seconds.
Everything works correctly, except when the user clicks on reload/refresh key, the timestamp is reset back to zero (0) and then he can access the login page.
How can i prevent this?

```
app.controller('LoginAttemptsController', function ($scope, $cookies, $log, $interval, $timeout) {

    var counter = 0;
    $scope.show = false;
    $scope.popup = false;
    $scope.newcounter;


    $scope.setcookie = function () {     

        $cookies['myCookieArray'] = {
            'key1': 10
        };

        getmycookiesback = $cookies['myCookieArray'];
        $log.info(getmycookiesback.key1);        

        stop = $interval(function () {                  
           $scope.setnewtimer( getmycookiesback.key1);
           getmycookiesback.key1 = $scope.newcounter;        
            console.log(getmycookiesback.key1);
        }, 1000);

    };

    $scope.setnewtimer = function (timer){

        if(timer<=0) {
            $scope.popup = false;
            $scope.newcounter = 10;
            $interval.cancel(stop);
            return $scope.newcounter;
        }

        else {
        $scope.newcounter = timer - 1;
        return $scope.newcounter;
        }

    };   

    $scope.timeoutInit = function () {
        $timeout.cancel($scope.timeOutSession);
        console.log('timeout handler invoked');

        $scope.timeOutSession = $timeout(function (timeOutValue) {
            $scope.startCountdown(); // initiates the countdown display
        }, $scope.timeOutValue);
    };


    $scope.checkAttempts = function () {

        var username = $scope.Username;
        var password = $scope.Password;

        if (username == 'kk' && password == 'kk') {
            window.location = "./home.html";
        } else if (username == 'kk' && password != 'kk') {
            $scope.show = true;
            $scope.alertMessage = "Sorry, we don't recognize this user";
            counter = counter + 1;

        } else if (username != 'kk' && password == 'kk') {
            $scope.show = true;
            $scope.alertMessage = "Sorry, we don't recognize this user";
            counter = counter + 1;

            /* empty the fields */
            $scope.username = '';
            $scope.password = '';
        } else if (username != 'kk' && password != 'kk') {
            $scope.show = true;
            $scope.alertMessage = "Sorry, we don't recognize this user";
            counter = counter + 1;
        }

        if (counter == 3) {
            counter = 1;
            $scope.popup = true;
            this.setcookie();
            /* window.location = '../login.html'; */
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: Login attempt throttling is not something that should be implemented on the client-side.

Comment: As @RobbyCornelissen said. It is not appropriate to do this client-side without also doing it on the server.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen and phuzi 47 thanks for your  feedback. I understand  this is not the best implementation for this. However, i only need this for quick demo purposes without necessarily having to implement it on the server side. Is there a way to do this without the back-end implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your contributions. I however got the solution to this. For more details on the work around visit https://github.com/emmonmoses/AngularJS-Session-Captcha-Throttle/edit/master/controllers/LoginAttemptsController.js

```
var counter = 0;

$scope.setCookie = function(){
    mycookie = $cookies.getObject('time');
    if(mycookie){
        console.log("exists");
        if(mycookie.suspendedTime = 0){
            $scope.timeobj = {
                suspendedTime : 0,
                suspendedMinutes : 0,
                suspendedSeconds : 0
            }
            $cookies.putObject('time',$scope.timeobj);
        }
        else{
            cookietime = $cookies.getObject('time');
            cookiesuspendedtime = cookietime.suspendedTime;
            currenttime = new Date();
            console.log(cookiesuspendedtime);
            console.log(currenttime.getTime());
        var timedifference = (cookiesuspendedtime - currenttime.getTime()) / 1000;
        console.log(timedifference);
        var minutedifference = Math.floor(timedifference/60);
        var seconddifference = Math.floor(timedifference - (minutedifference * 60));
            if(timedifference < 120){
                $scope.timeobj = {
                    suspendedTime : cookiesuspendedtime,
                    suspendedMinutes : minutedifference,
                    suspendedSeconds : seconddifference
                }
                $cookies.putObject('time',$scope.timeobj);
                this.suspension();
            }
            else{
                $scope.timeobj = {
                    suspendedTime : 0,
                    suspendedMinutes : 0,
                    suspendedSeconds : 0
                }
                $cookies.putObject('time',$scope.timeobj);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $scope.timeobj = {
            suspendedTime : 0,
            suspendedMinutes : 0,
            suspendedSeconds : 0
        }
        $cookies.putObject('time',$scope.timeobj);
    }
}
$scope.suspension = function(){
    $scope.popup = true;
    mycookie = $cookies.getObject('time');
    if(mycookie.suspendedTime == 0){
        newsuspension = new Date();
        newsuspension2 = newsuspension.getTime();
        console.log(newsuspension2);
        newsuspendedtime = newsuspension2 + 120000;
        console.log(newsuspendedtime);
        $scope.timeobj = {
            suspendedTime : newsuspendedtime,
            suspendedMinutes :2,
            suspendedSeconds : 0
        }
        $cookies.putObject('time',$scope.timeobj);
        console.log("suspended");
    }

    stop = $interval(function () {
        getMyCookie = $cookies.getObject('time');
        $scope.suspendedtime = getMyCookie.suspendedTime;
        $scope.Minute = getMyCookie.suspendedMinutes;
        $scope.Seconds = getMyCookie.suspendedSeconds;
        $scope.countdown($scope.Minute, $scope.Seconds);
        $scope.timeobj = {
            suspendedTime : $scope.suspendedtime,
            suspendedMinutes :$scope.Minute,
            suspendedSeconds : $scope.Seconds
        }
        $cookies.putObject('time',$scope.timeobj);
     }, 1000);
}

$scope.countdown = function (minutes,seconds){
    if(minutes == 0 && seconds == 0){
        $interval.cancel(stop);
        $scope.popup = false;
        $scope.suspendedtime = 0;
        $scope.Minute = 2;
        $scope.Seconds = 0;
    }
    else if(minutes == 0 && seconds != 0){
        $scope.Seconds--;
    }
    else if(minutes != 0 && seconds == 0){
        $scope.Minute--;
        $scope.Seconds = 59;
    }
    else if($scope.minutes != 0 && $scope.seconds != 0){
        $scope.Seconds--;
    }
}

$scope.checkAttempts = function () {
    var username = $scope.Username;
    var password = $scope.Password;
    if (username == 'kk' && password == 'kk') {
        window.location = "./home.html";
    } else if (username == 'kk' && password != 'kk') {
        $scope.show = true;
        $scope.alertMessage = "Sorry, we don't recognize this user";
        counter = counter + 1;
        $scope.username = '';
        $scope.password = '';
    } else if (username != 'kk' && password == 'kk') {
        $scope.show = true;
        $scope.alertMessage = "Sorry, we don't recognize this user";
        counter = counter + 1;
        $scope.username = '';
        $scope.password = '';
    } else if (username != 'kk' && password != 'kk') {
        $scope.show = true;
        $scope.alertMessage = "Sorry, we don't recognize this user";
        counter = counter + 1;
        $scope.username = '';
        $scope.password = '';
    }
    if (counter == 3) {
        counter = 1;
        this.suspension();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you should not do this only server side. But as you said you need this only for demo purposes, you can store the value of your counter variable in a cookie and increment its value whenever user enters wrong credentials.

Set cookie:

```
    $cookies['myCounter'] = 0;
```

Then fetch the cookie and update it if the user enters invalid credentials:

```
$scope.checkAttempts = function () {


    var counter = $cookies['myCounter'];


    var username = $scope.Username;
    var password = $scope.Password;

    if (username == 'kk' && password == 'kk') {
        window.location = "./home.html";
    } else if (username == 'kk' && password != 'kk') {
        $scope.show = true;
        $scope.alertMessage = "Sorry, we don't recognize this user";
        $cookies['myCounter'] = counter + 1;

    } else if (username != 'kk' && password == 'kk') {
        $scope.show = true;
        $scope.alertMessage = "Sorry, we don't recognize this user";
        $cookies['myCounter'] = counter + 1;

        /* empty the fields */
        $scope.username = '';
        $scope.password = '';
    } else if (username != 'kk' && password != 'kk') {
        $scope.show = true;
        $scope.alertMessage = "Sorry, we don't recognize this user";
        $cookies['myCounter'] = counter + 1;
    }

    if (counter == 3) {
        counter = 1;
        $scope.popup = true;
        this.setcookie();
        /* window.location = '../login.html'; */
    }
};
```

Also you can use ngStorage  for storing the counter variable in localStorage